# Adding text on an .xyz file of an atom

Tags: graphics, chemistry

I know it is possible to view [.xyz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format) files of coordinates in *Mathematica*.  I tried to write some text on a specific atom using [Text](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html), but I was not successful. How can i do that? 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Text` should work. For example

```
{g, n, p} = Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", 
    {{"Graphics3D", "VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}];

Show[g, Graphics3D[MapThread[Text, {n, p}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: OP can also style the text: `MapThread[Style[Text[##], 12, Bold, White] &, {n, p}]`